# System.Threading.Timer stopping on its own?

Tags: c#, timer, threadpool

There is a class which maintains a dictionary and a timer object. The dictionary gets periodically refreshed by a callback that the `System.Threading.Timer` obj is set up with. This has been working for years until recently when the timer just stopped on its own. There is minimal logging and no try catch around the callback (I just added it in my actual code), so I have no info on when this might happen again (unknown root cause).

My current suspect 2 different things. The first is a RAM issue. This refresh function runs as a small part of a way bigger application that is insanely memory intensive (think 94-95% memory dedicated to this if you opened Task Manager and checked it). When the memory issue becomes severe (97-99%), I am wondering if the machine is unable to grab a `ThreadPool` thread and provide it to the callback function. The machine it is running on is not always the same and offsite from me fyi. Anyways, has anyone seen a scenario where the callback does not find a thread and the timer just stops randomly? I thought the callback would schedule a thread or something. I am considering an edge case because I have tested it over days for small memory instances of same service and they run perfectly for a long long long time. However, the main ones carrying lots of traffic seem to face this struggle.

Alternatively, what happens if the callback gets stacked on each other. An example is, what if the `RefreshTheDictionaryMagicMethod()` takes longer than one minute (assigned refresh time) if it is hypothetically the first update (basically full populating the dict on first time), so the timer is due again before the first callback `ThreadPool` thread finished. The timer fires again and then what? Does another thread get grabbed for this process, is the process queued? I ask because the Refresh time use to be 5 minute intervals and it was changed to 1 recently. However, it ran at 1 min interval for more than one month before this and now it stops more frequently, hence why I think mem issue might be more likely.

Finally, what can I do right now? I have started by wrapping the `Callback` in a `try{} catch{}` block, but will an internal timer error or error in some deeper function surface to the callback? Is there a way to see these errors? If an exception is caught, can I somehow re create the timer and re init the callback.

Here is an example of what the code looks like

```
public class RefreshDict : IDisposable
{

public Timer myTimer;

public Dictionary<string, string> myDict;

public RefreshDict()
{
}

public void SetCallback()
{
    myTimer = new Timer(Callback, null, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
        Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
}

public void Dispose()
{
    if (myTimer != null) 
    {
        myTimer.Dispose();
    }
}

public void Callback(object state)
{
    RefreshTheDictionaryMagicMethod();
    myTimer.Change(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
}

public void RefreshTheDictionaryMagicMethod()
{
    // some query to a db and some updating a myDict object with new values
}
```

I have added the trycatch in my project but I really have no idea what I hope to see. Am looking for detailed edge case info or just a really deep and technical explanation of threading.timer which might indicate why it can just stop on me randomly. This setup has been working for many months and it is only now an issue where the timer will stop randomly.

Edit!!!

Forgot to update the thread but JonasH was correct. Basically, the thing which pulls in info to the dict had a weird behavior that caused first time pulls to be null and there were no logs or anything. This resulted in silent stalls.

Moral of the story, don't trust crap legacy code, don't feel bad about putting a crap ton of checks for null/invalidArg/empty, and logging is very useful. Also, just because senior eng. may say this is safe, treat all advice with a grain of salt! Fixed the bug above and also use try/catch/finally. No issues since!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess would be that you get some exception in your `RefreshTheDictionaryMagicMethod` that would prevent the timer from being restarted. If you have high memory usage this might occur due to either memory exhaustion, memory leaks, or memory fragmentation. I would not worry about concurrent invocations of the callback or the timer itself getting to some invalid state.

You mention catching exceptions, but not how. The most important thing is to actually log, or otherwise alert you what the exception actually is, and not just swallow it. You might also consider putting the `Change` call in a finally statement to ensure it always runs:

```
public void Callback(object state)
{
   try{
      RefreshTheDictionaryMagicMethod();
   }
   catch(Exception e){
   // log exception, or some other error handling
   }
   finally{
      myTimer.Change(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
   }
}
```

Note that exceptions might indicate a serious fault in your application, if you always restart the timer you might make this fault even worse. So the common wisdom is to log exceptions, let the application crash, and then fix whatever is causing the problem. If you run out of memory, reduce the memory footprint or buy more memory. You could also consider running your process as a service to use the inbuilt restart functionality.

Comment: Using the finally statement for the Change function is a better way to do things. I currently added the try {} catch {} like you show around RefreshDict(), but I have yet to encounter the error again. RefreshDict itself has a try{}catch{} for the area which can go wrong but it has never raised an error in logs thus far.

Comment: Based on this, I have different questions now. When memory gets exhausted (assuming mem issue) why does the timer fail but the service continue? My guess right now is that somewhere in callback it fails and never sets new timer due event. So the Finally block probably solves most issues. Just for sanity check, even if for some reason the callback fails and Finally sets new timer due event, will the timer work or will the timer get Disposed by GC? If finally block can keep the timer going despite this transient issue, I'm happy with this mitigation until I can investigate the root cause more.

Comment: @linglingslinguini No, if the timer is disposed, or the last reference released, it will stop functioning.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't solve your actual issue. In my opinion, you don't need to call the Timer's Change() method to do something on time. You just need to set the timing interval when the timer is initialized;

some code may like below:

```
public void SetCallback()
{
    /* call the Callback function immediately, 
then call the Callback function every minute */
    myTimer = new Timer(Callback, null, 0, 60000);
}

public void Dispose()
{
    if (myTimer != null)
    {
        myTimer.Dispose();
    }
}

public void Callback(object state)
{
    RefreshTheDictionaryMagicMethod();
}
```

Comment: This allows concurrent invocations of the `Callback`, something that the OP most likely want to avoid.

Comment: Hi, yeah normally I would opt to just set the callback period and not touch it again, but Theodor is correct. I would like to not create a concurrency scenario here.

Comment: Yes, I know the case you mentioned. One solution is to ensure that the Callback function is executed within one minute, or discard the result. @TheodorZoulias